# Using jQuery datepicker in a bootstrap input group addon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, datepicker

I've a `bootstrap input group`. A search field, a `date field`, a `dropdown` field for style, and the `search button`. In the `date field`, which is a span with class 'input-group-addon', I'm trying to add a `jQuery` `datepicker`.

I want it to look like this

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <form id="jumbotronForm" action="/Home/Events" method="get">
    <div class="input-group input-group-lg" style="padding-right: 200px;">
      <input id="jumbotronSearch" type="text" style="max-width: none;" class="form-control" placeholder="Location" aria-describedby="jumbotronDate">
      <span class="input-group-addon">08/28/2017</span>

      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button id="jumbotronStyle" type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" style="border-radius: 0px;" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Style <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
        <button id="jumbotronSubmit" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Search!</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

But the problem is that jquery date picker only runs in a input field.
So I tried inserting an input in the input-group-addon and it messes up the styling.

Shown here

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <form id="jumbotronForm" action="/Home/Events" method="get">
    <div class="input-group input-group-lg" style="padding-right: 200px;">
      <input id="jumbotronSearch" type="text" style="max-width: none;" class="form-control" placeholder="Location" aria-describedby="jumbotronDate">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><input id="jumbotronDate" value="08/28/2017" /></span>

      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button id="jumbotronStyle" type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" style="border-radius: 0px;" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Style <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
        <button id="jumbotronSubmit" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Search!</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I know `jQuery datepicker` will also run on a button, should I use that instead? I know I can add multiple buttons to an input group as addon's

Comment: Why not just set the input fields styles to background: transparent;
    border: none;

Comment: because there is more then just the background and border that's changed. It messes with the length and padding and other stuff

Comment: I switched over to using a button instead of an addon, and it looks good (no style change) but now the datepicker doesn't open.

Comment: Add this to your #jumbotronDate border:none; background:none; text-align:center; padding:0; and it looks the same as above

Comment: no it doesn't and the jquery datepicker is all off in its style as well. I'll try and post more code

Answer (score 0):

Just increase the z-index for the text box.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <form id="jumbotronForm" action="/Home/Events" method="get">
    <div class="input-group input-group-lg" style="padding-right: 200px;">
      <input id="jumbotronSearch" type="text" style="max-width: none;" class="form-control" placeholder="Location" aria-describedby="jumbotronDate">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><input id="jumbotronDate" value="08/28/2017" style="border:none; background:none; text-align:center; padding:0; width:100px" /></span>

      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button id="jumbotronStyle" type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" style="border-radius: 0px;  " data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Style <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
        <button id="jumbotronSubmit" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Search!</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: right, but there is too much padding or margins on the left and right side of the date

Comment: Yep just fixing that now

Comment: and because there is a change in the styling to the input inside the span, the datepicker doesn't align correctly with the span tag.

Comment: Any improvement?

Comment: I'm trying to use a button inside the input button group and it looks good, but I can't get the datapicker to show up.

Comment: How about something like this with the button class added to your div container: [link](https://jsbin.com/zipocewedo/edit?html,css,js,console,output)